# back stack and statically added fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-button, back-stack, fragmenttransaction

I have a fragment added statically from XML I want to replace this fragment by another fragment, I did that by adding this code:

```
        CFragment singleStationFragment = new CFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.layoutlist, singleStationFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```

the problem is that  when I press the back button the first fragment is not shown because it was not added through a transaction and the manager doesn't know about it, is there a way I could add the first fragment (ALREADY ADDED FROM XML), to my backstack or I could just show it when I click back instead of exiting the app ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you will have to add your first fragment to the activity in code rather than in the layout file. Do this with the `add` method of `FragmentTransaction`

```
transaction.add(R.id.FragmentContainer, fragment);
```

Comment: Sorry that didn''t work, I will try other solutions and update my post. Thanks and sorry for the late reply